# Using Automapper to update one item in a list of items

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable

I have a `private List<User> _userList = new List<User>();`. The `User` class has many properties within it, namely, `FirstName, Email, ..` etc. I want to selectively update just one of the items within the `_userList`
Consider the following method in my Class where I am passing in the `User` object which contains the updated values.

```
    public void Save(User saveThis)
    {
        var user = _userList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.RowId == saveThis.RowId);

        user = Mapper.DynamicMap<User>(saveThis);
    }
```

Since there are many properties on the `User` I am using Automapper to do the assignments. I don't need any mappings to be created since the source and destination are the same type. The code above also works till the second line where Automapper is called. The problem is I don't know how to put this updated object `user` back into the list of type `_userList`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the user, and then replace the object using the indexer (of the List) like this:

```
public void Save(User saveThis)
{
    var user_index = _userList
        .Select((item, index) => new {Item = item, Index = index})
        .Where(u => u.Item.RowId == saveThis.RowId)
        .Select(u => (int?)u.Index) //We case to int? to be able to handle the case where the user it not found if we want
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if(user_index == null) //We can handle the case if the user is not found
        return;

    var result = Mapper.DynamicMap<User>(saveThis);

    _userList[user_index.Value] = result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what exactly is happening in this line: `.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })`

Comment: For each item, this create an anonymous object that has two properties; the item itself and its index in the list.